# Create an IObservable sequence from an unidentified number of sequences

Tags: system.reactive

i have an observable sequence like :-

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(<source>, "PropertyChanged").Subscribe(changed =>
                {

}
```

Now my one property for which the above code fires also change 3-5 more properties, for each of which again the above code fires up.

Now i want to get to the last point of this sequence which i dont know how many times it will fire up.

i tried to create another IObservable sequnce from the above code, but dont know when will the new sequence that i create will be used. I tried :-

```
 Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(<source>, "PropertyChanged").Subscribe(changed =>
                {
                    if (testObs == null)
                    {
                        testObs = a(changed.EventArgs.PropertyName).ToObservable();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        testObs.Concat(a(changed.EventArgs.PropertyName).ToObservable());
                    }
}
```

On the whole i want to get to the end point of the sequence, that i am creating everytime that code on top fires up.

Any idea guys, Please help..!!

Comment: Not sure I understand. Who is consuming the secondary observable? You want to get to the endpoint of which sequence?

Comment: In simple words I want something which marks end of the top most block of code when it is fired from different sources

Comment: That is when it is fired from different properties of the <source>.

Comment: This isn't an observable issue - it's a property changed issue. You need to make sure that you don't raise the property changed event unless the value of the property actually changes. Something like `if (value != this.Value) { /* set value & raise event */ }`.

Comment: @enigmativity thanks for answering but only those properties are being fired up which are actually changing.. My scenario is multiple properties are changing on change of one... And I want to get to the end point from where I can get sure that no other prop is going to change so that I can execute my desired code...

Comment: @King - Then you could quite easily create an observable that fires when it has a period of time of inactivity on its source.

Comment: @King - Could you please post more of your code so that it is [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?